# Toast doesn't disappear from screen

Tags: android, toast

I have a problem with my simple android aplication that use GPS cords.

My class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener, and there is a static method call:

```
    String strText ="My current location is: " + "Latitude = " +  location.getLatitude() + " Longitude= " + location.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(GpsModule.cont, strText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Problem is with displaying this string. It's showing up, and never ends. When I press back button for main menu and even when I close application it's showing up constantly. Any clue? How can I resolve this problem?

GpsModule Class:

```
public class GpsModule extends Activity {

public static Context cont;
//public static WebView position;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gps);
    cont = getApplicationContext();
    //position = new WebView(cont);

    //position = (WebView) findViewById(R.layout.gps);
    //position.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locListener = new MyLocationListener();
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
}
```

MyLocationListener class:

```
@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
```

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();

    String strText ="My current location is: " + "Latitude = " +  location.getLatitude() + " Longitude= " + location.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(GpsModule.cont, strText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(GpsModule.cont, "GPS disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(GpsModule.cont, "GPS enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: Where do you call those lines?

Comment: is this called in a handler or any async task?

Comment: Are you sure it is not called constantly?

Comment: The line where you register your `MyLocationListener` would be interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the docs of the method [LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29).

Especially the parameter:

```
    minTime     minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds.
```

Try value 10'000 for every 10 sec. In production you should consider value more than mins.

Comment: Thanks for help. There was 2 problem:
- one with parameters in requestLocationUpdates()  - You resolved this, and thanks a lot
- one with showing Toast even after clicking Back button

Comment: Toast showing doesn't happen on UI thread. I don't think you can change that. You can look in to notification api.

Answer (score 3):

I think, you add your code in your location detection function and `LocationListener` is active. That means your Toast is called when GPS detect new location.

Comment: That's correct. What could be the possible solution? I added source of my classes. Could You have a look?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your location listener is active and repeatedly gets called. are you moving your device? LocationListener is called when the location changes.

Comment: Even when phone is not moving, location is changing because of number precision. For example:
50,00443558333333

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1 .

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), strText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

2 .

```
@Override 
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
}
```

3 .

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                Length, long, locationListener);
    }
```

Length and long should be more than 0.

Comment: Thanks for help. There was 2 problem:
- one with parameters in requestLocationUpdates ()
- one with showing Toast even after clicking Back button - You resolved this, and thanks a lot